# For the SST/CHROMIS H-β spectral line at 4846 Angstrom (Å), what is the difference in solar altitude observed at wavelengths differing by ±0.1 Å?

Tags: the-sun, solar-system

For the SST/CHROMIS H-β spectral line at 4846 Angstrom (Å), what is the difference in solar altitude observed at wavelengths differing by ±0.1 Å?